# How to press a button via WebBrowser - C #

Tags: javascript, c#, html, webbrowser-control

There is a button-link-javascript (select the correct), I need to push it through the WebBrowser control:

```js
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
```

```html
<a id="ctl00_plhMain_lnkSchApp" class="purplelink" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$plhMain$lnkSchApp','')">Press ME!</a>
```

I tried already all I know and all I could google. Through the TagName, ById, Foreach, but even nothing happens when you press it successfully.
Please, tell me how to push it and get the next page (or
form ??? because the address of page does not change).
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `InvokeMember` Method.

```
Webbrowser.Document.GetElementById('ctl00_plhMain_lnkSchApp').InvokeMember("click");
```

Comment: @RomanKovalchuk obviously you are doing something wrong. could you please post your code. then I can correct it

Comment: After start WebBrowser go to the page on which the button is. I put this code:
    browser.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_plhMain_lnkSchApp").InvokeMember("onclick");

on OnClick button event and got exception "System.NullReferenceException"